# Simplifying checks for undefined variables/properties

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am trying to find a more efficient way to evaluate object properties in `if` statements when the object itself may be `undefined`.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
var a = {'x':'hello'};
var b;

if(a.x) { console.log('hello'); }   // 'hello'
if(a && a.x) { console.log('hello'); }   // 'hello'

if(b.x) { console.log('hello'); }   // TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
if(b && b.x) { console.log('hello'); }   //
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/5kerc780/)

I find myself having to use the second syntax `if(b && b.x)` to check the object and then it's property.

**Is there a cleaner way I can do this?**

Comment: `b && b.x` is a common way so it won't be _wrong_, if it is clear is opinion based.

Comment: There is probably nothing more *runtime efficient* than using `&&`.

Comment: Could you please define *cleaner*?  What would be your preferred syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way to identify whether variable is undefined is by using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){};
```

In practice i am doing such operations in next way when i need one command to execute:

```
obj && obj.prop && console.log('hello');
```

When i am making some assignment i use `||`(or) operator and sure object `obj` exists:

```
var someVar = obj.x || obj.z;
```

It would assign first **non falsy** value to `someVar`, however it could be adjusted to using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to **catch especially "undefined" value**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some objects with similar structure, then create helper function and pass object to this helper.
Something like this?

```
function check(obj, prop) {
  if (obj && typeof obj == "object") {
    if (obj[prop]) console.log(obj[prop]);
  } else return false;
}

var foo = {x: 12};
var baz;
check(foo, "x");
check(baz, "x");
```

Comment: That will break for `baz = null` (if `null` should be treated the same as `undefined`, who knows).

Comment: Yep. Check updated version. Sure, both are very primitive.

Comment: That fails for objects created with `Object.create(null)`. `if (obj && typeof obj === 'object')` would work just fine.

Comment: Sure, but seems that's very exotic situation :)

Comment: Maybe, but it's more standard compliant. The `__proto__` property is not standard.

Comment: Yep, I forgot about versatility with Node. Updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkDeepProp = function (obj, deepProp) {
  var dp = (deepProp || '').split('.');
  var prop;
  var has = true;
  var initObj = obj;
  var i;
  var length = dp.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    initObj = initObj[dp[i]];
    if (typeof initObj === 'undefined') {
      has = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return has;
}

var has = checkDeepProp({a: {b: 'xcv'}}, 'a.b');
```

something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, an extra 5 characters (`b &&`), or 3 without the spaces (`b&&`), is going to be as clean as you're going to get.
If you want to get fancy, you can search the array of keys:

```
function (obj) {
   if( !!~Object.keys( obj || {} ).indexOf('x') ){
      ...
   }
}
```

Notice the `|| {}` in case the object doesn't exist.  Of course, what you'll notice is that it's always messier to try and determine if a variable holds an object, rather than assigning one in the first place.  For instance:

```
function( obj ){
   obj = obj || {}; // set to an object if it doesn't already exist

   if( obj.x ) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried

```
 if(b.hasOwnProperty('x')){

 // Your code here.

 }
```

Comment: That will throw an error because  if `b` is `undefined` so it wouldn't really help.

Comment: Please explain your solution